# Gettings bytes from string

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, asp.net-core

Hey I'm implementing hashing password in my app and I have couple questions.

I'm using the following class to do this.

```
public class Encrypter : IEncrypter
{
    private static readonly int SaltSize = 40;
    private static readonly int DeriveBytesIterationsCount = 1000;

    public string GetSalt(string value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Value cannot be empty.");
        }

        var saltBytes = new byte[SaltSize];
        var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        rng.GetBytes(saltBytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
    }

    public string GetHash(string value, string salt)
    {
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(value, GetBytes(salt), DeriveBytesIterationsCount);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(pbkdf2.GetBytes(SaltSize));
    }

    private static byte[] GetBytes(string value)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[value.Length * sizeof(char)];

        Console.WriteLine(value.Length*sizeof(char));

        Buffer.BlockCopy(value.ToCharArray(), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Why in GetBytes method I shouldn't use just

> String.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)

instead of current implementation of this method?

Why the paramteres passed to

> pbkdf2.GetBytes(SaltSize))

is a salt size?

Why the results of GetSalt, and GetHash methods should be converted to base64?

P.s I know that #encryption tag is not appropriate for this subject, but maybe programmes  which are interested in encryption can help me.

Comment: There are too many questions here to really have any sort of answer be useful to anyone. Try to limit to one question per question. You could always post the same sample code and ask a different question each time and get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple answers here:

> Why the paramteres passed to `pbkdf2.GetBytes(SaltSize)` is a salt size?

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.`GetBytes(int cb)` creates a pseudo-random key for the given object at the byte size specified. [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Why the results of GetSalt, and GetHash methods should be converted to base64?

Making an assumption here, but I'm going to go with **readability**. A byte array is difficult for humans to read and store, while a Base64-encoded byte array is straightforward.

Comment: Your statement about "unless you own the incoming string and can confirm it is truly UTF8" makes no sense. The incoming string is a `System.String`. Any decoding already took place before it became a `string` instance.

Comment: I have one more question - why GetSalt method need value parameter? This is not used anywhere.

Comment: @bielu000: I can't speak for the author of the code, but it appears as though it's used for validation of the input, and that's about it.